# how write whmcs inner join 'where condition'

Tags: php, mysql, whmcs

whmcs inner join 'where condition',

both table having same field.

how distinguish table name in where condition ?

tried this one ,

```
$table = "tblclients";
$fields = "id,firstname,lastname,domain";
$where = array(
   "lastname"=>array("sqltype"=>"LIKE","value"=>"Demo"),
   "companyname"=>array("sqltype"=>"NEQ","value"=>""),
);
$sort = "id";
$sortorder = "ASC";
$limits = "0,5";
$join = "tblhosting ON tblhosting.userid=tblclients.id";
$result = select_query($table,$fields,$where,$sort,$sortorder,$limits,$join);
```

how specify table name in where condition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$where = array(
   "table1.lastname"=>array("sqltype"=>"LIKE","value"=>"Demo"),
   "table2.companyname"=>array("sqltype"=>"NEQ","value"=>""),
);
```